# If the bed you last slept in is destroyed or mined, where do you respawn when you die?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In particular this is useful to know when one is exploring. I tend to put a bed down, sleep for the night, and pick it up again before I continue exploring.

In this case, where would I respawn if I died?

Perhaps where the bed was, or the bed I previously slept in, or my original spawn location?

Answer (score 5):

After a bit of digging through the properties of the bed, I found this, hope this helps answer your question:

> The bed is in no way tied to a player's spawn point - the game only
> checks for the presence of a bed at a player's spawn point when the
> respawn button is clicked from the death screen. The bed may be
> destroyed, replaced, reoriented, etc. and will still serve as a spawn
> point for players so long as it exists when the player tries to
> respawn. If a player's bed is destroyed or the bed is surrounded by
> solid blocks and the player dies when the player had set his
> spawnpoint there, a message is displayed saying Your home bed was
> missing or obstructed, and the ***player will respawn at the original
> spawn point**.*

[Source](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Bed#Usage)

Comment: This is correct.

Answer (score 2):

In this situation of placing a bed, sleeping, and then removing the bed, you would not respawn at that location if you died. You would instead respawn at the world's original spawn point. In order to respawn at a bed, the bed still needs to be there when you die. If your bed is removed or obstructed, you will respawn at the world spawn point with the message *'Your home bed was missing or obstructed.'*

So, if you're just sleeping for the purposes of passing the night so you can explore in relative safety, there's no problem with removing the bed. **If you are sleeping for the purposes of setting your spawn, you must leave the bed behind in order to maintain that spawn point.**